# Avoiding warning message “There is a result object still in use” when using dbSendQuery to create table on database

Tags: r, database, dplyr, teradata, dbplyr

**Background:**

I use `dbplyr` and `dplyr` to extract data from a database, then I use the command `dbSendQuery()` to build my table.

---

**Issue:**

After the table is built, if I run another command I get the following warning:

```
Warning messages:
    1. In new_result(connection@ptr, statement): Cancelling previous query
    2. In connection_release(conn@ptr) :     There is a result object still in use.
    The connection will be automatically released when it is closed.
```

---

**Question:**

Because I don’t have a result to fetch (I am sending a command to build a table) I’m not sure how to avoid this warning. At the moment I disconnect after building a table and the error goes away. Is there anything I can do do to avoid this warning?

Currently everything works, I just have this warning. I'd just like to avoid it as I assume I should be clearing *something* after I've built my table.

---

**Code sample**

````
# establish connection
con = DBI::dbConnect(<connection stuff here>)

# connect to table and database
transactions = tbl(con,
                   in_schema(“DATABASE_NAME”,”TABLE_NAME”))

# build query string
query_string = “SELECT * FROM some_table”

# drop current version of table
DBI::dbSendQuery(con,
                 paste('DROP TABLE MY_DB.MY_TABLE'))

# build new version of table
DBI::dbSendQuery(con,
                 paste('CREATE TABLE PABLE MY_DB.MY_TABLE AS (',
                       query_string,
                       ') WITH DATA'))```
````

Comment: Which part produces the error? Care to create a working example (e.g. using sqlite)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even though you're not retrieving stuff with a SELECT clause, DBI still allocates a result set after every call to `DBI::dbSendQuery()`.
Give it a try with `DBI::dbClearResult()` in between of `DBI::dbSendQuery()` calls.

`DBI::dbClearResult()` does:

```
Clear A Result Set
Frees all resources (local and remote) associated with a 
result set. In some cases (e.g., very large result sets) this 
can be a critical step to avoid exhausting resources 
(memory, file descriptors, etc.)
```

The example of the man page should give a hint how the function should be called:

```r
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT 1")
print(dbFetch(rs))

dbClearResult(rs)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Comment: Works with PostgreSQL too. Exactly solved the issue.